# Ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException, при чтении пустого списка

Tags: java, исключения

```java
>код из одного класса
try {
     CFG.getDeploymentArchitecture().getApplicationSystems().forEach(appSys -> {

            if (appSys.getGitConfig() == null) {
                appSys.setGitConfig(new GitConfig());
            }                

             verticalLayout.addComponent(createGitSettingsPanel(
             "Репозиторий прикладной системы " + appSys.getName(),
              appSys.getName(),
              getGitConfig(),
              resourceBundle));
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.severe(e.getMessage());
            Notification.show("Какие-то проблемы :" + e, Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            LOGGER.severe(e.toString());
     }
```

```java
> вот метод из другого класса, который я вызываю
   private List<AppSystem> applicationSystems;

public List<AppSystem> getApplicationSystems() {
        applicationSystems = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        if (applicationSystems == null) {
            applicationSystems = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return applicationSystems;
    }
```

почему возникает ошибка?
Collections.EMPTY_LIST; это же должно ее предотвратить

Comment: В какой строке возникает ошибка NPE? Старайся не использовать последовательность вызовов, типа `getA().getB().getC()`, т.к. в этом случае сложнее найти строку с ошибкой. И что в логах? В java я обычно использую log4j, которая позволяет логировать весь след (stack) ошибки.

Comment: 29-Dec-2019 21:49:40.592 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-285] ru.gr.cds.gui.admin.RepositoryControlComponent.<init> null
29-Dec-2019 21:49:40.594 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-285] ru.gr.cds.gui.admin.RepositoryControlComponent.<init> java.lang.NullPointerException
в логах вот что, очень мало информации

Comment: ошибка возникает вот в этой CFG.getDeploymentArchitecture().getApplicationSystems().forEach(appSys -> { строке

Comment: Если мало логов, значит, их нужно добавить. И переписать код, избавившить от цепочки вызовов. Тут нет Ванги

Comment: пытался полный стек трейс писать, ничего не было кроме этих двух строчек, даже не знаю как их дополнить

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, `applicationSystems = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;` при каждом вызове метода `getApplicationSystems()` будет присваивать значение неизменяемого пустого списка полю `applicationSystems`. Скорее всего эта строчка лишняя.

А NPE ошибка падает из-за того, что либо `CFG` , либо `СFG.getDeploymentArchitecture()` возвращают `null`.
Попробуй поставить `debug` на этой строчке и посмотреть какие значения у них.

Comment: я не могу узнать их значения, но я могу проверить их на null (проверил null они не равны)